# Negative gain in Ziegler-Nicholas Oscillation Method?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, pid-control

For a plant G(s), the transfer function is given by:
$$G(s) = \frac{(10s+50)}{s(s^2+20s+2500)}$$

Using Ziegler-Nicholas method to get the parameter: $k_p = \dfrac{-1000}{3}$ and $w =-28.868j$.

Is it correct? what should I do in case of negative $k_p$ and how do I calculate the PID parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ziegler-Nichols cycling method is not appropriate for this system. Because of the zero located in -5, the closed loop system is always stable and will not oscillate for proportional compensator (poles will never be conjugated on top of the $j\omega$ axis), as can be evidenced by the root locus plot:

[image]

If you still wish to use the Ziegler-Nichols table for this system you should use a different approach, like the step response method.

Comment: I got all the parameters for a PID controller using the PID tunner in MATLAB, but I need to show the calculations for the parameters. So which approach should I use? Our course content only has Z-N oscillation method in detail..

Comment: Since you already have a "desired" closed-loop transfer function (from the tuning you've done), you could use the diophantine equation approach. Link: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Polynomial_Design